# SQL Database Design Many to Many

Tags: sql, database-design

I am creating a database based on a sporting game to store matches and each player involved in each match.  I am having trouble resolving a many to many relationship.  I currently have the following tables:

**Player**

```
id
name
```

**Match**

```
id
date
```

**PlayerMatch**

```
player_id
match_id
home_team
goals_for
goals_against
```

There will always be a minimum of two players in a match.  Is this the best design for this approach?

Comment: Do you have only one player per match?

Comment: Just edited, there will always be at least two players in a match

Comment: So, is it possible to have more than two players in a match? BTW, by player you mean a team or a person?

Comment: A person, think it will just be two for the moment but I can't see how more will make a difference?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Because usually a match is composed by two teams (or players), so, in this case you would not need the N-N relationship anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a sticking with a many to many relationship.  This allows you to change the specifications of how many players you can have in a game easily while not complicating the data model much.

**Player**

```
id
name
```

**Match**

```
id
date
```

**PlayerMatch**

```
player_id
match_id
is_home
goals_for
goals_against
```

Foreign key from `PlayerMatch` to `Player`

Foreign key from `PlayerMatch` to `Match`

```
    --All the matches a player has played in.
    SELECT m.* 
    FROM Player p
    JOIN PlayerMatch pm
        ON p.id = pm.player_id
    JOIN Match m
        ON m.id = pm.match_id
    WHERE p.id = /*your player Id*/

    --All the players in a match
    SELECT p.*
    FROM Match m
    JOIN PlayerMatch pm
        ON m.id = pm.match_id
    JOIN Player p
        ON p.id = pm.player_id
    WHERE m.id = /*your match Id*/

    --player information for a single match.
    SELECT pm.*
    FROM Player p
    JOIN PlayerMatch pm
        ON p.id = pm.player_id
    JOIN Match m
        ON m.id = pm.match_id
    WHERE p.id = /*your player Id*/
        AND m.id = /*your match Id*/
```

Comment: Thanks, im unsure yet as to whether to stick with just 2 players or like you say leave it open to the option of recording more on the data model.

Comment: Good, then I think a many-to-many relationship will be useful.  Also, you'll probably want to put some thought into `home_team`, `goals_for`, and `goals_against`.  It's a trivial problem if players never change teams.  However, I expect you'll allow players to change teams :).

Comment: It's not actually linked to a team, it's just an individual.  home_team really doesn't matter that much, I could actually remove it or change it to home_player

Comment: So I think you'll probably want `home_team` then to be `isHome`

Comment: Yep, any idea how i'd get all the match information involving a player in piece of SQL?  e.g. so that I have date, goals_for, goals_against, opposing_player_id

Comment: I've added a query to my answer that should help you.  Also, you can select `pm.*` in either of the first two queries.

Answer (score 1):

That is a valid option, though I would suggest a naming convention where you use the same column name in both tables (i.e. use match_id in both Match and PlayerMatch; same for player_id).  This helps make your SQL a bit more clear and when doing joins in some databases (MySQL) you can then use the 'using (col1, col2, ...)' syntax for the joins.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the many-to-many relationship, I would do like this:

**Player**

```
id
name
```

**Match**

```
id
home_player_id
guest_player_id
date
goals_home_player
goals_guest_player
```

Comment: This works well for exactly two players but is not extensible if the OP wants to expand the specifications for a game.

Comment: I see... but he wasn't convinced that the game was going to be played by more than two players. I will rethink. Thanks.

Comment: I read through the comments. It looks like he actually said _at least_ two players.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd try to model the match first & then see what happens with the table design :

```
Match
-------------
match_Id
player1_Id
player2_Id
player1_Goals
player2_Goals
```

Where player1_Id and Player2_Id are both foreign keys onto the Player table

```
Player
---------
Id
Name
```

By convention player1 would always be the home team

then you would query it like

```
Select p1.name as player1_Home, p2.name as player2_away, 
matchId, 
player1_Goals as homeGoals, player2_Goals as awayGoals           
from Match m 
inner join Player p1 on p1.id = m.Player1_Id 
inner join Player p2 on p2.id = m.Player2_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of data relationship is not at all unnatural.  To set it up, just ask yourself two questions:

- Do players have more than one match?
- Do matches have more than one player?

If the answer is yes to both, then you have a many-to-many relationship and these are not at all uncommon.  Their implementation is only slightly more complicated.  In a one-to-many relationship, you'd hold a foreign key to a list of records in some table.  As it happens, this is still how it works in many-to-many relationships, except that both the Players and the Matches table will need a foreign key to some list of records.

This list is called the Bridge Table.  So you'll need to use a total of three tables to descrive the relationship

```
Players
-------
player_id
<player attribute columns, eg last_name, first_name, goals_scored, etc.>

Player_Match
------------
player_id
match_id


Matches
-------
match_id
<a list of columns that are match attributes, eg. match date, etc.>
```

The table in the middle of the diagram above is called a bridge table, and it does nothing more than map players to matches, and it also maps matches to a list of players.  Often, bridge tables have only 2 columns, each representing a foreign key to one of the bridged tables.  There is no need for a primary key in a bridge table, and if there is not one, it means that a player can have more than one of the same match.  If a player can have only one of one kind of match, then make the primary key for each row of the bridge table a composite key on both of the columns.

In database design, normalization is a highly desirable relational goal because it provides a database with the greatest possible flexibility and the lowest amount of redundancy.  To normalize, ask yourself if the data you want to put in a table is -really- an actual attribute of the object described by the primary key.  For example, is the home_team an actual attribute of the match.  I would say no, it is not.  In this case, you should replace home_team in your PlayerMatch table with a foreign key to a Teams table.  In your Matches table, you ought to have two columns.  One for a home team foreign key, and one for the away team key.  The teams are not actual attributes of a match and so to normalize the Match table, you'd want to put those data in tables of their own.

Comment: I kind of burned myself in my own suggested design.  "Goals scored" is not an actual attribute of a person.  Many people have never scored any goals at all.  In a fully normalized database, this column would be replaced by a foreign key to a "Goals" table (a list of dates and times goals were scored).  The "number of goals scored" by that player could be determined by performing a query on the data base that exploited the relationship between the Players and the Goals table.

Answer (score -1):

Agree with M Hagopian, the op schema looks like a good start.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette :)

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation and link. Now if I can only figure out how to add a comment to someone's answer. :(

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23211/how-do-i-add-a-comment-to-an-answer